# Escape Characters in a resource file string?

Tags: vb.net

I've been globalizing an application and have been using Resx Manager to make my life easier.  I ran into a multi-line string literal and it stumped me.

How would I handle the escape characters when making this string into a resource?

```
If Not RelayMessage(
    "Are you sure you want to do the selected action?" & vbCrLf &
    "A confirmation message will be sent to the user." & vbCrLf &
    "Please ensure you want to perform this action before hitting accept.",
    My.Resources.Confirmation, RelayMessageOptions.Confirm_YesNo) = 
        DialogResult.Yes
```

How would I make that string into a resource?

Comment: What's RelayMessage? Can you show the code for it? Is it pulling a localized version of this message? If yes, would it not be easier to give it a more programmer friendly name, such as Area_Subarea_MessageTitle?

Comment: You'd use copy/paste to get a multi-line string into the Resources designer.  Probably something similar in an extension like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard VS resource manager (is this the manager you're using?) you can enter a multi-line string resource directly in the editor by using <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

Note that this is actually stored as a string with CR+LF pairs, assisted by the `space="preserve"` attribute.  Viewing the .resx file in a text editor:

[image]

Results using a standard message box:

```
MessageBox.Show(strings.myString)
```

[image]

Comment: I am using [Resx Manager](https://resxresourcemanager.codeplex.com/documentation) it looks pretty similar.  I found out that control + enter is the key for this function in the tool.

Comment: My main question was just a matter of being a noob to resource files and whether or not, if it's displayed as having 3 lines in the resource Value, it will actually display that in the messagebox?

Comment: All you do in your original Messagebox declaration is concatenating strings with string constants. If you add the line feed in the editor it inserts the respective control characters and displays them as a line feed. In the background the string that is return from your concatenation and what is actually saved in the ressource file is the same string.

Comment: See my update - as @Jens says, it stores and retrieves your entered string verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it is usually handled in globalization problems. But an easy way would be to define your own escape character formats. For example you could define `\n` as a newline character. When you actually use your ressource you could then use

```
If Not RelayMessage(Strings.Replace(myResourceString, "\n", vbCrLf),
    My.Resources.Confirmation, RelayMessageOptions.Confirm_YesNo) = 
    DialogResult.Yes
```

instead of

```
If Not RelayMessage(myResourceString,
    My.Resources.Confirmation, RelayMessageOptions.Confirm_YesNo) = 
    DialogResult.Yes
```

Or you could manually add chars with character codes 10 and 13 (e.g. `ChrW(10) & ChrW(13)`) at the `vbCrLf` location in your ressource string. This equals a `vbCrLf` (meaning a carriage return (10) + line feed (13)). This would avoid manipulation of the source code. Other stuff like Tab (9) have codes, too. These are called control characters. Take a look at the wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Comment: .NET strings use Unicode/UTF-16, not ASCII. (But, yes, the codepoints 9, 10, and 13 are the same in both.)

Comment: Good point Tom. I still always have the ascii character chart from the QBasic Help in the back of my head, and think in terms of that. But times have changed. I slightly edited my answer to avoid confusion. :-)